# How to save table order row order after reordering it using kendo ui jquery? I dont know how to save the order into the database

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-ui

```
// Kendo table sortable
var kendoSortable = grid.table.kendoSortable({
    filter: ">tbody >tr",
    hint: function (element) { // Customize the hint.
        var table = $('<table style="width: 600px;" class="k-grid k-widget"></table>'),
            hint;

        table.append(element.clone()); // Append the dragged element.
        table.css("opacity", 0.7);

        return table; // Return the hint element.
    },
    cursor: "move",
    placeholder: function (element) {
        return $('<tr colspan="4" class="placeholder"></tr>');
    },
    change: function (e) {
        var skip = grid.dataSource.skip(),
            oldIndex = e.oldIndex + skip,
            newIndex = e.newIndex + skip,
            data = grid.dataSource.data(),
            dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));

        grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
        grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);
    }
});
```

Im trying to save the order after dragging and reordering. to the database so that when i reload the page the order where i have ordered it would be the exact order when i am reaordering it

Comment: But what is your problem? Can't you save to the database? Don't know how to get current sort order? Be specific.

Comment: I dont know how to save the new order of rows into the database

Comment: So your question should not be related to kendo it seems. What data provider are you using? How do you read data from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using the [change](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/sortable/events/change) event for the Sortable widget. This event provides the `oldIndex` and `newIndex` positions for the item that was moved.

Below is an example of one way to go about getting the reordered items and then sending that data to the server to save the changes. Hopefully, this will help you get started with solving your problem.

The `change` event firing indicates the item has been sorted and the item's position has changed in the DOM. Looking at the `change` event below, I'm getting the data items for the current page of the grid into `currentGridView`. Then I'm using the `slice()` method to get the items between the `oldIndex` and `newIndex`. Then I call the `updateSequence` function.

The `updateSequence` function creates an array to store objects to be passed to the server. These objects are based on the `DataSequenceModel` class. Basically, I just need to know the Id and the new sequence for each item that has been reordered. After this I'm using a basic Ajax POST to send the data to the server.

Index.cshtml - Here is a [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ogICuSEv) based on Telerik's [Integration - Grid](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/integration-grid) demo and updated with my changes.

```html
<div id="grid"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            // ...Basic grid setup
        }).data("kendoGrid");

        grid.table.kendoSortable({
            filter: ">tbody >tr",
            hint: $.noop,
            cursor: "move",
            placeholder: function(element) {
                return element.clone().addClass("k-state-hover").css("opacity", 0.65);
            },
            container: "#grid tbody",
            change: function (e) {
                // Get the indexes and data items that have been reordered.
                var skip = grid.dataSource.skip(),
                    oldIndex = e.oldIndex + skip,
                    newIndex = e.newIndex + skip;

                var currentGridView = grid.dataSource.view();
                var dataChanged = currentGridView.slice(oldIndex, newIndex + 1);
                updateSequence(oldIndex, dataChanged);
            }
        });
    });

    function updateSequence(startIndex, dataChanged) {
        // Create array to be passed to Controller. Based on DataSequenceModel class.
        let data = [];
        let newSequence = startIndex;
        for (var i = 0; i < dataChanged.length; i++) {
            data.push({ Id: dataChanged[i].ProductID, NewSequence: newSequence });
            newSequence++
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'https://localhost:44395/Test/UpdateSequence',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

TestController.cs

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public bool UpdateSequence(IEnumerable<DataSequenceModel> data)
    {
        // ...Logic to update sequence in database.
        return true;
    }
}
```

DataSequenceModel.cs

```
public class DataSequenceModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NewSequence { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro! professionals like you deserve a raise :)